# JSON.net combine 2 list(Of JObject) together

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

Heyy all I am trying to combine **2 JObject lists**. I have **2 list(Of JObject)** named **masterJsonList.Add(jsonWriter.Token)** and **masterJsonListNA.Add(jsonWriter.Token)**.

I have not found anything when searching Google that shows me how to combine JObects **masterJsonListNA** to **masterJsonList**.

When I try:

```
masterJsonList.Add(masterJsonListNA) '<-- error here
Dim finalJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(masterJsonList, Formatting.Indented)
```

It gives an error of:

> Error BC30311 Value of type 'List(Of JObject)' cannot be converted to 'JObject'.

I have even tried the following with no luck as well:

```
masterJsonList.Concat(masterJsonListNA)
Dim finalJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(masterJsonList, Formatting.Indented)
```

Although there is no error using **Concat**, I only get the **masterJsonList** values in **finalJson** and not both **masterJsonList** & **masterJsonListNA**.

```
masterJsonList.Union(masterJsonListNA)
Dim finalJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(masterJsonList, Formatting.Indented)
```

And again using **Union** there is no error, but I also again only get the **masterJsonList** values in **finalJson** and not both **masterJsonList** & **masterJsonListNA**.

I know it works if I do this:

```
Dim combinedJsons As Object = masterJsonList.Concat(masterJsonListNA)
Dim finalJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(combinedJsons, Formatting.Indented)
```

But I would like to know if that's the *correct way of doing this*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your final guess is correct. The extension methods `Concat`, `Union`, etc. don't operate on the object they're invoked on. Instead they return new object containing the result of the operation. You actually don't need to us `As` clause for the `combinedList` - let the compiler to infer it, like so:

```
Dim combinedJsons = masterJsonList.Concat(masterJsonListNA)
```

But if you don't need the `combinedJsons` for anything else you can `Concat` the lists in place of the first parameter to `SerializeObject`:

```
Dim finalJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(masterJsonList.Concat(masterJsonListNA), Formatting.Indented)
```

On the other hand, the `List<T>.Add()` method do work on the instance it is invoked on, BUT it adds objects of type `T`, not whole lists of type `T`.

Comment: @StealthRT: Hey, no problem. Glad you got it. I forgot to mention that you can use `List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)` to add your second list to the first one. `AddRange` will mutate the list it is invoked on to contain the added list.